# How do I elegantly check for presence of both the object and associated objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an instance variable `@tally_property`, and if there are `photos` on that object I would like to cycle through the photos and show them.

So my code snippet looks like this:

```
<% if @tally_property.photos.present? %>
   <% @tally_property.photos.each_with_index do |photo, index| %>
```

The issue is that based on the above, if `@tally_property` is nil, then the entire first line throws an error.

So is there a 'nil' check I can do that isn't bulky, i.e. I don't want to do `if @tally_property.nil?`, on both the primary object and the association, and is elegant and ruby & rails-esque?

Comment: You have the & (lonely operator), but it counts as a nil-chek, so, you really need to return something else in case @tally_property is nil, as it won't respond to `photos`. You can introduce a decorator for that.

Answer (score 3):

I would use the safe navigation operator ([`&.`](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11537)) and write something like this:

```
<% @tally_property&.photos&.each_with_index do |photo, index| %>
  ... 
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby 2.3.0+ you can use the safe navigation operator:

```
@tally_property&.photos
```

ActiveSupport has a `.try` method that can be used to the same end in older versions of ruby:

```
@tally_property.try(:photos)
```

You can add a simple conditional to be able to safely iterate through the collection:

```
<% (@tally_property.try(:photos)||[]).each_with_index do |photo, index| %>

<% end %>
```

Rails 4 adds `ActiveRecord::Relation#none` and a change in behaviour so that associations always return a `ActiveRecord::Relation`. So its perfectly acceptable to write:

```
<% @tally_property.try(:photos).try(:each_with_index) do |photo, index| %>

<% end %>
```

After upgrading your app. Or you can use a partial and render:

```
<%= render partial: 'photos', collection: @tally_property.photos if @tally_property %>
```

Which removes the need for writing the iteration.

Comment: `@tally_property.try(:photos)` will return nil in case @tally_property nil, no? if so, it also forces you to add an extra `try`.

Comment: try(:photos)||[]) or maybe try(:photos), []) ?

Comment: @YuriyVerbitskiy `nil.try(:foo, "bar") == nil`

Comment: @YuriyVerbitskiy `try(:photos)||[])` is a syntax error.

Comment: Sorry, its true

Comment: @max, I would do as you suggested in comment to question, iterating `ActiveRecord::Relation` with `each` +++

Comment: @YuriyVerbitskiy `try(:photos), [])`  was actually my first though too as it would be quite logical if second argument was a default value. `.try` actually works like `Object.send` - the remaining arguments are passed to the method. `"foo|bar".try(:split, "|") == ["foo", "bar"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `&&` (or `and`, they each have their sweetspot).

Taking it out of Erb for a moment, I would generally write something like this:

```
if @tally_property and @tally_property.photos.present?
```

Depending on `photos` I might use:

```
if @tally_property and @tally_property.photos
```

or perhaps:

```
if @tally_property and not @tally_property.photos.empty?
```

Sometimes I'll use a temporary variable:

```
if (photos = @tally_property && @tally_property.photos)
  photos.each #…
```

That kind of thing.

I would recommend this episode of Ruby Tapas, [And/Or](https://www.rubytapas.com/2013/08/15/episode-125-and-or/) for a longer (but still quick) look at it.

Answer (score -1):

One more way, just select all photos connected to this tally_property:

example how it might be:

Photo.joins(:tally_property).each_with_index do |photo, index|

Comment: But those photos aren't the ones belonging to the `@tally_property`, but all the photos belonging to a tally property, no?